# Power BI - Dynamic Table with Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a Dataset like this

| patient_name | age | gender | test_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 48 | M | Positive |
| Joe | 35 | M | Negative |
| Divya | 45 | F | Positive |

And in my power BI Dashboard i need to display a free form table like below

| Item Description | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Total number of Adult-Male Patients with Positive Test Result | 1252 |
| Total number of Adult-Female Patients with Positive Test Result | 856 |
| Percent of Positive | 2.8 |

I have the measures created for calculations. I tried to create a custom table with measures, but they are not changing dynamically. The table is showing only static values, when slicer selected value changes.
Is there a better way to present this ?

Thank you,
NSR

Comment: What calculations, what slicer? Your problem isn't reproducible. Are you just looking for some general comments?

Comment: which age is adult for you ? over 18 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create an empty table

```
    let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i44FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Item Description" = _t, Value = _t])
in
    Source
```

then we will fill this table with your measures by creating a table...

Modelling --> New Table

```
    Report Table =
UNION (
    Report,
    ROW (
        "Item Description", "Total number of Adult-Male Patients with Positive Test Result",
        "Value",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNT ( 'Table'[test_result] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ),
                    'Table'[test_result] = "positive"
                        && 'Table'[gender ] = "m"
                        && 'Table'[age ] > 18
                )
            )
    ),
    ROW (
        "Item Description", "Total number of Female-Male Patients with Positive Test Result",
        "Value",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNT ( 'Table'[test_result] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ),
                    'Table'[test_result] = "positive"
                        && 'Table'[gender ] = "f"
                        && 'Table'[age ] > 18
                )
            )
    ),
    ROW (
        "Item Description", "Percentage Positive",
        "Value",
            FORMAT (
                DIVIDE (
                    CALCULATE (
                        COUNT ( 'Table'[test_result] ),
                        FILTER (
                            ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ),
                            'Table'[test_result] = "positive"
                                && 'Table'[age ] > 18
                        )
                    ),
                    CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'Table'[test_result] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )
                ),
                "Percent"
            )
    )
)
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

did you try `ALLSELECTED` in your measures?

```
Total number of Adult-Male Patients with Positive Test Result =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Table'[test_result] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ),
        'Table'[test_result] = "positive"
            && 'Table'[gender ] = "m"
            && 'Table'[age ] > 18
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the measures already created for both male adult count and female adult count. But how to display the info in a free form table like the one i have given above ?  Can we create a dynamic table with columns 'Item Description' , 'value' ?

Comment: @nsr yes, it is a bit long shoot actually...